# Why my computed is undefined

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-router, vuex

I created an application which uses axios (+vue-axios) to get data from JSON file to Vuex store. I also use Vue-Router for different views for my application.

1. In my main component (`App.vue`) I display `<router-view>`
2. My view component is `Slides.vue`
3. When 2. is `created()` I do

   ```
   created(): {
     this.$http.get('./static/data/slides.json')
       .then(({ data }) => {
         this.$store.state.slides = data;
       })
       .catch((error) => {
         console.log(error);
       });
   },
   ```
4. In that component (`Slides.vue`) have `Slide.vue` component which get `:slides="slides"` prop:

   ```
   <Slide :slides="slides" />
   ```
5. Inside `Slide.vue` I have in `<script>`:

   ```
   props: ['slides'],
   computed: {
     slideId() { return this.$store.state.activeSlide; },
     slide() { return this.slides[this.slideId]; },
     slideTitle() { return this.slide.title; },
   },
   ```
6. In `<template>` i use `{{ slideTitle }}` to display title

When I try to run this, I have an error in `Slide.vue`:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: this.slide is undefined"

Why is this happening?

When I change `this.slide.title` to `this.slide` it seems to work (but display all data from JSON file which is not what I want)

Comment: You shouldn't change the `state` of your vuex `store` like that you should use `mutations` or `actions`

Comment: Actually he should dispatch `actions` which in turn will commit `mutations`.

Comment: You can modify `state` with just `mutations` and without dispatching `actions`

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the problem is related to `this.slideId` being undefined before the `created()` call to the store is resolved -or at anytime-. This causes the computed property `slide` to be `undefined` -since it resolves to `this.slides[undefined]`.
 At the end, the computed property `slideTitle` resolves to `undefined.title`, thus throwing an error.

If I am right, you can overpass this problem by modifying your `slideTitle()` computed property as follows:

`slideTitle() { return this.slide && this.slide.title; }`

Said so, there is a problem in your `created()` hook, when you do:

`this.$store.state.slides = data;`

You're manipulating the store state directly. This is forbidden by vuex and will cause all kind of errors. Instead, [you should use a mutation](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html) to modify the store state.